# kde-ghost in ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: kde

How to install kde ghost theme in Ubuntu 15.04. I just need the ghost theme, so should i install kubuntu-full or is there any other specific method. Please help me out.

Comment: What is the ghost theme. A link would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the theme settings (`kcmshell5 desktoptheme`), click the **Get new themes** button, search `Ghost`.